# Interop.Word.Document.Words border changes very slow

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-addins

Hi!

I'm working on a MS Word addin that marks certain words in a given text. Unfortunately, this operation is very slow. In a document of 50 pages (~26'000 words) changing the border style for about 1'100 words takes up to 15 minutes.

I already turned of ScreenUpdating, but that does not really help!

Here's what I'm doing:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
.....
Words words = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Words;
words[i].Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
words[i].Borders.OutsideLineWidth = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt;
words[i].Borders.OutsideColor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorDarkTeal;
```

What exactly makes this so slow? What can I do to speed things up?